# Beginner in calibrating HE3D Prusa XI3

Tags: prusa-i3, calibration

This is my first time calibrating my printer and I'm not sure where to start. The printer is running Repetier v0.91 firmware that came on the SD card that came with the printer.

Anyway, the question I have is where do I start calibrating and how would I go about it? I have read on Google many ways and it seems there are different opinions. I am reading this at the moment: [RepRap Wiki - Calibration](http://reprap.org/wiki/Calibration).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a great tutorial [**here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TiEw...zECor3EbqF8euw) on youtube.

And personally my favourite is this [**tutorial.**](http://reprap.org/wiki/Triffid_Hunter%27s_Calibration_Guide)

Comment: The first youtube link is broken.

Comment: Instead of using non-descriptive `here`, or `tutorial` as link text, it is better to include the _actual_ title of the link, so that people can search for the item, in case the URL is corrupted - as is the case here...